# android how to scroll a view inside NestedScrollView to top of the screen how

Tags: android, kotlin, android-nestedscrollview, nestedscrollview

I have a `NestedScrollView` contains `LinearLayout` with orientation vertical, i have adding multiple views programmatically to the linearLayout, after that i need to click on a specific view inside the `nestedScrollView` and when clicking i need to make the view scrolling to the top of the screen. i used this but it doesnt work

```
   val scrollTo: Int = groupView.bottom //groupView is the view i clicked on and i need to scroll it to the top of the screen
   nestedSctollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 mNestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: what is `mRecyclerView ` here ?

Comment: me i have a linearlyout inside the nestedScrollView only

Comment: thank you..please what is LayoutManager here ?

Comment: @Malo try this line only  mNestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);. I have refined it now

Comment: this line scroll to the top of NestedScrollView.. i want to make the view inside the NestedScrollView on top of the screen when i click on it ..it is different